# SignalR hub connection corrupts viewstate after few postbacks

Tags: viewstate, signalr

I have written a chat app using signalR. It's a ASCX control containing the markup and the javascript that runs the chat. The page that holds the user control has a updatepanel that renders asynchronous and allows the user to refresh some content specific to a entered code. The problem is, I can click as many times the refresh button and the page behaves without any problem. When I click to connect the chat (which is all build in JavaScript) and I click a couple of times the refresh button it appears to behave fine but suddenly the page brakes and some viewstate errors are logged saying : The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted. Invalid view state.. blah blah...  it's an ugly error.

This only happens when I connect to the hub. If I don't initiate the connection this never happens.

One thing to mention though, the code behind of the control stores some value in a property that refers to the viewstate (without storing it in the viewstate the page brakes on every postback) that later is written in the markup so the scripts that initiate the chat know who should be part of the conversations.

Please help.

Some code here:

StandAlonePanel.aspx -> contains the updatepanel with the refresh button.
ChatControl.ascx ->

```
public int userId{
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["UserID"] == null)
                ViewState["UserID"] = 0;
            return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["UserID"]);
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["UserID"] = value;
        }
    }
//--- Same for userName

if (userId == 0 && CurrentUserSession.User != null)
{
   this.userId = CurrentUserSession.User.Id;
   this.userName = CurrentUserSession.User.Name;
}
```

in the markup

```
var userInfo = {
    userId : "<%= userId %>",
    userName : "<%= userName %>",        
    IsAnonymized: "<%= IsAnonymized %>",
    enableLogging: "<%= enableLogging %>"
}



if (chat != null) {
      chat.Disconnect();   
   }



chat = new Chat(userInfo);
   chat.Connect();
```

//-- The script conn

```
var hubConn = $.hubConnection(url);

hubConn.logging = self.enableLogging
hubConn.qs = { 'u': userInfo.userId, 'tc': '0', 'oo': userInfo.showOnlineOnly, 'ach': self.IsAnonymized, 'lgch': self.enableLogging }; /* Initiating queryString */


hubConn.error(function (error) {
    logMe(error);
});

var hubProxy = new ChatProxy(hubConn);

/* hook up callbacks to hubProxy */

self.Connect = function () {
    if (self.longpolling == true) {
        hubConn.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).done(function (result) {
            ///--            
        }).fail(function (error) {
            ///--
            alert("error" + error);
        });
    }
    else {
        hubConn.start().done(function (result) {
            ///--            
        }).fail(function (error) {
            ///--
            alert("error" + error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this "Refresh" do?  Is there code for it?

Comment: It's a complicated process. In a glance.. the code checks if some number exists in the db, otherwise goes to and query for it in some system (PACS system). When the info is retrieved then some information is refreshed in the page

Comment: I guess I'm closing this question because it only happens in my asp dev env. when I deploy the app to iis it does not present the same problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is to localized

Answer (score -1):

I guess I'm closing this question because it only happens in my asp dev env. when I deploy the app to iis it does not present the same problem